# Segues and UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, segue

This may be trivial, but I'm really stuck.

I have 2 `UIViewControllers` with a button on each to navigate between them

> Home ---- > View 2 
>  View 2 -----> Home

The 'Home' `UIViewController` has a `UIScrollView` with the view 2 button at the bottom.

Is there a way to return to the 'Home' view with the `UIScrollView` still in the position it was before?

I'm using Swift xcode 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method could be that you store the scrollView's `contentOffset` property in a variable before you change views. Then, when you return to 'Home', you can use the `scrollView.setContentOffset` method to scroll to that position again. In fact, if you call `setContentOffset` with the animaton bool set to false within Home's viewWillAppear(), it should achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like

> Home → View 2 → another Home instance → Another View 2 instance

or something like

> Home ⇆ View 2

I'm guessing you want to go from a Home instance to a new View 2 instance and go back to the existing Home instance.
If your case is the latter, then what you should use is an [unwind segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) to go from View 2 to Home.